# On OSX, how do I route all traffic from Pandora through my WiFi connection?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, routing

When I am at work, Pandora is blocked on my LAN. (ethernet connection) We purchased a cable connection and have a wireless router hooked up just for this reason. How do I route all traffic to/from pandora.com through only this interface?

I did it on Linux by creating a static route. I've googled around a bit but can't seem to find anything interface specific. Everything seems to just want me to create a static route based on what my default gateway is. Unfortunately, I use this laptop everywhere... so that changes.

Comment: If you did it in Linux, then why not just do similar and create a static route in OSX?  That IS what you should be aiming to do, but I'm unclear on what you mean by "interface specific"?  You create a route specifying the network and what gateway/interface to use to get to it, that's how static routes work.  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: On linux, I was able to route traffic by interface, not just gateway. I'm sure it's possible on OSX too, I just haven't been able to find how. (hence why I asked here) Even though I CAN do it via IP (all traffic to/from 208.85.0.0/16 via gateway) my address and gateway change when I get home or change to a different network.

Comment: and no, I've read that question. That is IP specific. The IP will change. I roam on a few different WIFI networks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the interface priority higher on your OSX.
Taken from Apple support website: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH7119

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences and click Network.
2. Choose Set Service Order from the Action pop-up menu (looks like a gear).
3. Drag a service, such as Ethernet, to the top of the list.
4. Click OK, and then click Apply to make the new settings active.

In your case, you want to drag your WiFi connection up above the Ethernet connection.